# make Jtable non-editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table which is clickable but when I double click, instead of doing what it is told, it goes editing mode. I have tried isCellEditable() method with no success. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public AllResultsFromDB(GUI x) {
   final Vector columnNames = new Vector();
   final Vector data = new Vector();


        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metad.getColumnName(i));
        }


        //  This loop gets the data inside the rows

        while (rset.next()) {
            final Vector row = new Vector(columns);


            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(rset.getObject(i));

            }

            data.addElement(row);
            //data.addElement(b);
        }

        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();


        //  Create table with results

      final JTable  table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {


            public boolean isCellEditable() {
                           return false;
                       }



            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {

                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {


                    Object obj = getValueAt(row, column);




                    if (obj != null) {

                        return obj.getClass();

                    } 
                } 

                return Object.class;
            }


        };


        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());

            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                //System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                if(e.getClickCount()==2){


                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
            }

            }
        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not that far off.

The actual method `isCellEditable` takes two parameters, so your method isn't actually overriding anything.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29

for the correct method.

Comment: That doesn't help me... I know it needs int but I don't know how to do it! Please see my code and tell me what needs to be changed! I am going crazy!

Comment: Jack has laid out what is needed. All I can do further is suggest you go through: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 3):

The method `isCellEditable` that you tried to override has a different signature which is:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
```

How could you specify which specific cell otherwise? Next time adding an `@Override` annotation should help spotting this.

In any case this is not the correct way to make a `JTable` non-editable. The correct way is to provide a custom `AbstractTableModel` which returns false with its `isCellEditable` method. The `JTable` shouldn't decide if a cell is editable, it's duty of the model to decide it: indeed the isCellEditable method of `JTable` just asks to its model if the cell is editable. The `JTable` shows the content, nothing more, it's the model that decides and contains the data.

Since you seem to use just basic features of a JTable you don't need to roll your own table model, a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) will work for you, and you can overrite its `isCellEditable` method.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it doable with my code the way it is now? If yes how would you do it? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
{
                
                return false;
                }`

This is the answer. I had just to place this under the table initiation!